# & condition not working - newbie question tradingview pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I have the following code which gives stochastic crossovers. I want to add an `AND` condition so that `crossBelow` pops up only when `stochK` and `stochD` are both above `80`. And `crossAbove` pops up only when `stochK` and `stochD` are both below `20`.
Any help would be appreciated. I did try various `AND` code, but get compiler errors.

```
//@version=4
study(title="example", overlay=false)

stochK = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 14), 3)
stochD = sma(stochK, 3)

crossBelow = crossunder(stochK, stochD) 
crossAbove = crossover(stochD, stochK) 

plot(series=stochK, color=color.orange)
plot(series=stochD, color=color.teal)

plotshape(series=crossunder(stochK, stochD), style=shape.flag , color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, transp=0)
plotshape(series=crossunder(stochD, stochK), style=shape.flag, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
crossBelow = crossunder(stochK, stochD) and min(stochK, stochD) > 80
crossAbove = crossover(stochD, stochK) and max(stochK, stochD) < 20
```

[image]

Comment: would appreciate your assistance on next query How to locate recurring instances of crossovers & trigger alerts in pinescript. very grateful!